# When is Rails Eager loading by default for all association a good idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

At which point is good to make all queries on a large project to eager load all of the objects associations?
Let me explain the background of this question.
Currently i am working on a project that has become quite complex in terms of models and associations. I started to check the server logs and saw that some views were taking some time to load because of the nested objects contained in the queries.
So i begin to refactor some of these queries to something like this:

```
@process = current_account.processes.query(params)
```

To this:

```
@process = current_account.processes.includes(:messages, :parts, :people).query(params)
```

The result was pretty good. In some views i was able to reduce the view render time and activerecord query time by 70%.
Man i was happy, so i decided to make more. But after this decision, i started to notice that not all places i refactored the code, the changes were good. In fact, there were queries that became slower.
To explain a little more about the problem i have a model like this:

```
class Process
  has_many :anotations
  has_many :publications
  has_many :movimentations
  has_many :reunions
  has_many :profiles
  ...
```

And each one of these nested models inside `process` `belongs_to :user` that created it like this:

```
class Anotation
  belongs_to :user

class Reunion
  belongs_to :user

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
```

And it go on.
In my `show view` of `process`, there is several tabs that display **all** of these nested objects and the name of the user that has added it to the current process.
With a query like this:

```
@process = current_account.processes.query(params)
```

It was performing kinda slow. So i tried something like this:

```
@process = current_account.process.includes(:anotations, :publications, :movimentations, 
  :reunions, :profiles, :messages).query(params)
```

This has made me gain speed on the view rendering, but in activerecord, the the time to retrieve these objects have increased significantly. And it raised to the skies when i eager loaded the `user` object inside of all nested models of `process` like this:

```
@process = current_account.process.includes({:anotations => [:user]}, 
  {:publications => [:user], etc...).query(params)
```

Well, refactoring the design of the app to behave differently with these associations is not going to happen, so i ask the question again.
At which point is good to make all queries on a large project to eager load all of the objects associations?
Any tips/best practices/experience on the subject would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest a title like "When is Rails Eager loading by default for all association a good idea?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"all queries on a large project to eager load all of the objects associations" - almost never. At least not without help inside the application.

Were I in your shoes, I'd start looking at caching (which you didn't mention, so I have no idea if you are doing any). Fragment caching in particular as it would seem to fit your tab structure well.

In one app I used a context sensitive sidebar to display a list of groups of items, each group containing links to related items (n items in any of 18 groups), each item showing the name of the related item in a link form (and a couple of other small data items).

Each group in the sidebar was cached, and each related item's entry in its group was cached as well. Controller refactored to accumulate the related items as @relateds, and that code made use of the caches to determine whether the fetch was necessary (on a cache miss).  With a little work in intelligent cache expiration, performance was very good.

Supposing Project X had 10 related items in each of 12 categories (120 related items).  On the first show for Project X, you pay the price. Changing the name of 1 related item in a category would invalidate the cache for that item, that item's group, and the overall sidebar.  On the next show for Project X, reconstruction of the sidebar involved 1 cache miss for 1 item (reading that item's record with a join or two), so that item cache got rebuilt, the one category cache rebuilt from the 10 item caches (1 new + 9 existing), cache hits for the other 11 categories (not reading those 110 related items), and yielded a rebuilt sidebar cache at the end.

Feels like you could adopt a similar strategy for your tabs, perhaps even finer grained, but that's up to your implementation.

Comment: That's a good point of view. I have never look into caching mechanisms before, so i guess i would have to check it out. Do you have some good sources of caching material(tutorials/documentation/etc)?

Comment: It's been a while since I did he research, but a quick browse yielded this article, which seems to cover the topic fairly well...   http://broadcastingadam.com/2011/05/advanced_caching_in_rails/

Comment: I didn't use "sweepers" to expire caches. That logic was built into a cache_management method that accounted for what data changed. Changing the name of something generally expired all the caches for an item since the name always appeared in a fragment, while changing a data element that wasn't displayed in the sidebar for example, wouldn't expire the sidebar caches for that item.